# Simple questions about Pattern and MatchQ

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-test

1st Question :

Note that

```
In[1] {MatchQ[1, Sin[_]], MatchQ[1, f[_]], MatchQ[1, Plus[_]], 
 MatchQ[1, Times[_]], MatchQ[1, Power[_]]}

Out[1] {False, False, True, True, True}
```

But I think `Out[1]` should be

```
{False, False, False, False, False}
```

Because the expression '1' is just '1'.
There isn't any head like Sin, f, Plus, Times, Power.
Why is it so?

2nd Question :

```
In[1] MatchQ[f[g[1]], (f@*g)[_]]
Out[1] True

In[2] MatchQ[f[g[1]], _(f@*g)]
Out[2] False
```

But I think Out[2] should be `True`,see the Mathematica document for Blank (_). Why is it so?

3rd Question :
Because of the example in 2nd Question, it is unsafe to say `_f` and `f[_]` are equivalent. After experiencing this, the following question arose naturally : Is there any merit using `_blahblah` like expression? I feel it is not intuitive, and dangerous. Using `blahblah[_]` looks intuitive, not dangerous.

Comment: 1st question: see [`OneIdentity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OneIdentity.html). 2nd question: See  `FullForm[(f@*g)[_]]` and `FullForm[_(f@*g)]` (and also [`HoldPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html)). 3rd question: `_f` is more equivalent to `f[___]` (see [`BlankNullSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html)), with some exceptions regarding [`AtomQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AtomQ.html) expressions (and expressions that evaluate prematurely). As for why you'd use the former: Convenience mostly

Comment: note that `_f` is not meant to be equivalent to `f[_]`; rather, it simply states "the [head](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) of the matched expression is `f`". as you can see, `Head[f[g[1]]]` is `f`, not `f@*g`; likewise the `Head`s of `AtomQ` expressions @Lukas Lang mentioned are not "visible" (the expression is an atom, not a "compound" like `f[a,b,...]`), e.g. check out `{Head[3], AtomQ[3], MatchQ[3, _Integer], MatchQ[3, Integer[___]]}`

Comment: @LukasLang For the first question, the issue is that `Plus[_]`, `Times[_]` and `Power[_]` evaluate to `_`. It has nothing to do with the `OneIdentity` attribute.

Comment: @CarlWoll good point. Although you could probably argue that the fact that they do evaluate that way is due to the attribute. Nevertheless, it's definitely a better and easier explanation of the behavior in the question